# How to exclude source code from coverage measurement in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-coverage, test-coverage

In a project, I have a *Utility class* which looks like this:

```
public final class Util {
    private Util() {}
    public static String method1(InputStream in) {...}
    public static String method2(BufferedReader in) {...}
    public static String method3(File file) {...}
}
```

The class is a Utility class in the sense that it contains *only `static` methods*.
Therefore it is declared `final` and its **constructor is `private`**.
Creating instances or deriving subclasses would simply not make any sense.

I have a suite of unit tests which tests the project.
I am using *IntelliJ IDEA* to run the tests, measure and visualize the code coverage.
The constructor of the Utility `class Util` now brings down coverage.
I would like to see a 100% on 100% logical coverage.
Code like the private constructor of the Utility class brings down the coverage.

**Is there a possibility, preferably by means of an annotation, to mark a method or constructor as not relevant for code coverage in order to exclude such code from the coverage reports and thus getting a 100% coverage displayed?**

I know that in general hiding code from the coverage report is lying to your own disadvantage. I wouldn't mind if the report would have a list of "ignored items" - actually, that would be good, to check if someone is ignoring stuff which shouldn't be ignored. The point is really about code for which coverage makes no sense, like the private constructor of a Utility class.

I've tried to find if `annotations.jar` contains a candidate. The only annotation which looked even remotely as if it could do it was `TestOnly`, but it does not fulfill this purpose.
I also peeked around in `plugins/coverage/lib/*.jar` and couldn't find a candidate, but maybe I just missed it?

**Update**
This question is obsolete now. Meanwhile, IntelliJ IDEA as well as Jacoco learned how to ignore the coverage of private constructurs that don't have callers. I do not know of any other example of intentionally unreachable code in Java that would spark a conversation for exclusion from coverage reports.

**Update 2**
This question may become relevant again about the accessors of Java record classes.

Comment: You appear to be interpreting the coverage report wrong. Code that isn't covered could be interpreted as needing more tests, or it could be considered an indication of a code smell. In this case, it's a smell -- you really should be avoiding utility classes like this, it's more than likely an artifact of bad design and you should try to fix that rather than game your coverage report. Gaming reports like this is one of the biggest problems with metrics programs, and if you were on my team we'd be having a talk about what it is you think you're doing right now.

Comment: For someone who does not know the real code in question, I think you're using quite strong and dogmatic language. I agree that Utility classes can be a smell and people should be warned about them. But just because something is often bad, doesn't mean it's always bad. Anyways, using `enum` now, as suggested by Peter Lawrey. And it makes perfect sense, as this is a class with a predefined (empty) set of instances, and coverage is happy now. P.S.: Happy to have that talk if in your team. I would feel no longer lonely about preaching Clean Code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use `enum` for utility classes and most coverage tools know to ignore it's methods.

```
public enum Util { ;
```

`enum` are `final` with `private` constructors by default.

Comment: I've tried this, and it works! I also tried to use an `interface`, but that only works if there are no `private static` methods. It helps me in the current situation. I'm still hoping for a more generic solution.

Comment: You can add dummy tests or nested classes to call private methods to get your 100%

Comment: You're right, I could, but that's something I wanted to avoid as well.

Comment: You could write a method which calls all the methods of a class which have an annotation. Thus way you could mark methods to be ignored.

Comment: Meanwhile, JetBrains has even implemented "Utility class should be an enum" as inspection. How nice of them. :)

Comment: You could use default method implementations in an interface too (in java 8), but that would be just as wrong as misusing enums for this purpose. If you're going to violate good design principles, accept that this is what you're doing and accept the lower coverage score -- if you game it you're covering up your dirty design and hiding the technical debt that you've introduced.

Comment: @EngineerDollery if there is a small and fixed number of instances `enum` is the only way to do this. Using any other class is a hack imho.

Comment: @PeterLawrey my point was actually that one shouldn't be doing this at all, and that a hack is a hack whether it's the best hack or the worst. I think there's a lot of weight in the argument that util classes are an antipattern and in various ways violate OO. If you're going for an OO solution, it seems that they should be avoided completely.

Comment: @EngineerDollery I agree that util classes are not OO, but if you want pure OO you should not use FP like stream and lambda either. If you want to use Java, you should use all its features and recognize it's not a pure language by design.

Comment: Utility classes aren't always bad, and the API contains justified examples for utility classes, like `java.lang.Math`, `java.util.Arrays` and `java.util.Collections` and `java.nio.file.Paths`. I like pure functions without state - and they are implicitly static. If you have a topic which delivers pure functions only, have no state, and need no polymorphism, then "Utility" classes with `static` methods are the correct thing to do - everything else would be misleading and an abuse of programming paradigms.

Comment: It is natural for object-functional programs to have more static methods than object-oriented programs. And there are good reasons why we are (finally!) adding functional programming to our "toolbox".

Answer (score 4):

This question is currently over a year old; however, I thought I could offer an alternative to ignoring private constructors in unit tests.  Although fairly unlikely, it is possible to circumvent a private constructor in Java.  Also, its possible the class could be modified in the future, someone could add a constructor etc...  Having a unit test verifying this can feel redundant, but it does add another level of clarity of intent.  A failing unit test would certainly catch my eye, "I caused a unit test to fail, am I sure I know what I'm changing here?"

Without further ado here is some sample code.

Here we have a class with a private constructor.

```
public final class ClassWithPrivateCtor
{
  private ClassWithPrivateCtor()
  {
    throw new AssertionError(String.format(
      "Illegal instantiation of class: %s.",
      this.getClass().getName()));
  }
}
```

This is one way to invoke a private constructor in Java.

```
private static <T> void invokePrivateConstructor(final Class<T> type)
  throws Throwable
{
  final Constructor<T> constructor = type.getDeclaredConstructor();

  constructor.setAccessible(true);

  try
  {
    constructor.newInstance();
  }
  catch (InvocationTargetException ex)
  {
    throw ex.getTargetException();
  }
}
```

And this is how I use it in my unit tests.

```
@Test(
  description = "Verify ClassWithPrivateCtor private constructor fails.",
  expectedExceptions = AssertionError.class)
public void classWithPrivateCtorTest()
  throws Throwable
{
  invokePrivateConstructor(ClassWithPrivateCtor.class);
}
```

I've made it a habit to verify private constructors this way just to be clear about the original intent of the class whether its a utility class or a class with constants etc...